Check if \tikZ \pic is defined or not
I have to draw \tikZ \pic's based on .csv input data which I don't have under my full control.
So at compile time, I want to check, if a \tikZ \pic is defined or not. In case it is not defined, a default \pic should be printed.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/default/.style={
        code={
            \draw[thick,red] (1,1) circle(2.5);
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{
    pics/pic1/.style={
        code={
            \draw[thick,red] (1,1) rectangle(5,5);
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\CheckPicDefinition}[1]{
    % If \pic is defined do this
    \tikz{\pic{#1};}
    % Else do this
    \tikz{\pic{default};}
}

\begin{document}

\CheckPicDefinition{pic1}

\end{document}


The handlers .try, .retry and .lastretry make it possible to let PGFKeys to the needed checks:
\pic{#1/.try, default/.retry};

This will silently draw nothing if default is also not defined.
If a missing default pic should raise an error use .lastretry:
\pic{#1/.try, default/.lastretry};


Of course, if you need to do more based on the existence of #1 than just use another pic, you can still use the .try handler and simply work with \ifpgfkeyssuccess afterwards.
In both approaches, there's only one \tikz\pic sequence which means you don't have to repeat code.

Key handler ⟨key⟩/.try=⟨value⟩

This handler causes the same things to be done as if ⟨key⟩=⟨value⟩ had been written instead. However, if neither ⟨key⟩/.@cmd nor the key itself is defined, no handlers will be called. Instead, the execution of the key just stops. Thus, this handler will “try” to use the key, but no further action is taken when the key is not defined.
The TeX-if \ifpgfkeyssuccess will be set according to whether the ⟨key⟩ was successfully executed or not.

Key handler ⟨key⟩/.retry=⟨value⟩

This handler works just like /.try, only it will not do anything if \ifpgfkeyssuccess is false. Thus, this handler will only retry to set a key if “the last attempt failed”.

Key handler ⟨key⟩/.lastretry=⟨value⟩

This handler works like /.retry, only it will invoke the usual handlers for unknowns keys if \ifpgfkeyssuccess is false. Thus, this handler will only try to set a key if “the last attempt failed”. Furthermore, this here is the last such attempt.

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  pics/default/.style={code={\draw[thick,red] (1,1) circle [radius=2.5pt];}},
  pics/pic1/.style   ={code={\draw[thick,red] (1,1) rectangle (5,5);}},
  pics/check pic definition/.code=%
    \pgfqkeys{/tikz/pics}{#1/.try}%
    \unless\ifpgfkeyssuccess
      \pgfqkeys{/tikz/pics}{default}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand*\CheckPicDefinitionA[1]{\tikz\pic{#1/.try, default/.retry};}
\newcommand*\CheckPicDefinitionB[1]{\tikz\pic{check pic definition={#1}};}
\begin{document}
\CheckPicDefinitionA{pic1}
\CheckPicDefinitionB{pic1}
\end{document}


Of course, \ifpgfkeysdefined is just as valid and could also be used in check pic definition for the same effect.

Amazing, that's it!

you can use \pgfkeysifdefined,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/default/.style={
        code={
            \draw[thick,red] (1,1) circle(2.5);
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{
    pics/pic1/.style={
        code={
            \draw[thick,red] (1,1) rectangle(5,5);
        }
    }
}

\newcommand{\CheckPicDefinition}[1]{
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/pics/#1/.@cmd}{%
        \tikz{\pic{#1};}%
    }{%
        \tikz{\pic{default};}%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\CheckPicDefinition{pic1}


\CheckPicDefinition{pic2}

\end{document}

output:

